# How To incorporate TurboParser Instead of MaltParser for improved results like from online demo?

Tags: nlp, srl

I have successfully installed Semafor on Linux Mint 18.1 and I can run it. But the results I get from my version differs drastically from the online demo. I realized that online demo uses TurboParser, not MaltPraser. I tried A LOT to download TurboParser's model, but the remote host is sending data on 100 KB/s which is so lousy while I can download from other web sites at about 1 MB/s! But I kept on downloading and finally received a corrupted file. Now I have a request and a question:

1. Can any one upload the model on a better host? Maybe a Google drive or so?
2. How can TurboParser be incorporated in Semafor? I could not figure it out because I failed to download the model.